# Partition of a graph by disjunct paths

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given is a planar, undirected, connected graph $G$ with at least one vertex of degree $1$ (called endpoints). I want to partition $G$ by disjunct paths. The paths are defined by walks where each edge can only be used once. A path starts at a selected endpoint, and then walks through the graph. The walk stops if another endpoint is reached or if no further walk is possible because the edges were already used by previously defined paths or are already part of the currently walked path.

I want all possible partitions by disjunct graphs.

Here are $2$ simple examples with $2$ possible partitions where the disjunct paths are colored.

[image]

Is there a special name for this problem?

Which algorithm could solve this?

Is there a Python implementation?

The problem appeared [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4499356/737314).

Comment: This is not exactly the same, but I think that the term [linear arboricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_arboricity) might help you.